# Which services read the /etc/securetty configuration file?

Tags: security, configuration, tty

Which programs / services are parsing contents of `/etc/securetty` configuration file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The `securetty` manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/securetty.5.html) lists two users of `/etc/securetty`: some versions of [`login`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/login.1@@shadow-utils.html), and [`pam_securetty`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/pam_securetty.8.html). The intention in both cases is to limit the terminals on which `root` can log in.